# how to get ipv6 address for ubuntu server

Tags: api, ubuntu, server

i have ubuntu server and i have ipv4 address to access that server.
have create API services for IOS application but not that ios application need IPV6 for calling that api. how to find that using command prompt.
so i am not able to get IPV6 from my server.
please help tp get ipv6 appdress.
thanks in advance

Comment: iOS applications can work with IPv4 or IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Does your hosting provider enable IPv6 for your server?

If yes, you should be able to read it using `ifconfig` - you look for your network interface and check the `inet6` field.

Better, you add to your DNS an AAAA field, and use the url of your website to access the APIs. To change your DNS entries, please read documentation of your hosting provider.

Answer (score -1):

ip -6 addr show then on inet6 you will find ipv6 address assuming you are using ubuntu 16.04 or newer